# Tracking videos from OOyala player through Omniture

Tags: adobe-analytics, ooyala

I have a video implemented in my html page. The video is configured from Ooyala player. I need to do video tracking through Omniture. I have already made the below changes in appmeasurement.js file. Also have configured custom variables but still couldn't track video analytics in omniture. Any help on this would be deeply appreciated.

```
s.Media.autoTrack= true; s.Media.trackVars="events,prop3,eVar1,eVar2,eVar3"; s.Media.trackEvents="event9,event10,event8,event12,event11,event13,event7" s.Media.trackMilestones="25,50,75"; s.Media.playerName="ooyalaplayer"; s.Media.segmentByMilestones = true; s.Media.trackUsingContextData = true; s.Media.contextDataMapping = {   "a.media.name":"eVar2,prop3",   "a.media.segment":"eVar3",   "a.contentType":"eVar1",   "a.media.timePlayed":"event8",   "a.media.view":"event9",   "a.media.segmentView":"event10",   "a.media.complete":"event7",   "a.media.milestones":{
     25:"event12",
     50:"event11",
     75:"event13"   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Amit,

Check out [Ooyala Player Omniture Plugin](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/concepts/pbv4_analytics_omniture.html) on the support site.
This integration uses the Adobe Heartbeat SDK to publish video-related events, such as video plays, quartile video completion rates, and content metadata to your instance of Adobe Marketing Cloud automatically as well as adding more events as custom events if needed.

Based on the limited information you provided, did you get the default events being sent to your Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. Just one more thing. Can we use OOyala version 4 with omniture video milestone tracking. While going throughthe ooyala support document I couldn't find anything on that. Please provide your inputs.